# Mongodb date is off by 1 hour

Tags: mongodb

I am running mongodb on ubuntu server. The server time is

```
root# date
Thu Sep 13 21:15:58 BST 2012
```

But when I run the following command I get a different result

```
root# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
connecting to: test
> new Date()
ISODate("2012-09-13T20:15:58.670Z")
```

There is exactly one hour difference. When I update a documents `updated_on` field with php using `MongoDate()`, the value of the field is still 1 hour off.

[EDIT]
Actually I just checked my php error log and the time in the log file is 1 hour off as well

```
[13-Sep-2012 20:11:14 UTC] Log Message (Time should be 21:11:14)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongo tells you

```
2012-09-13T20:15:58.670Z
```

Z = Zulu time / Zero offset / UTC.  You can also express the time in that TZ as 2012-09-13T20:15:58.670+00:00, as defined in [the ISO8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) by the way.

BST is UTC+1.  So, they are the same time but in different time zones.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.How can I make Mongo tell me the time in BST? And why php log file has the same problem?

Comment: Maybe the server is running in UTC without time zone?  Check its TZ definition.  And the logfile isn't "off" either, it just lives at the same moment in time but in a different time zone :-)

Comment: :) I thinks this is more about ubuntu then mongodb or php :) Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You can resolve this issue by displaying the DateTime with `ToLocalTime` method.

MVC C# Example: `@Model.StartDate.ToLocalTime()`

This is due to the way MongoDB store datetime in BST format. So the daylight savings time or the time zone of the server will have an effect on the actual date time returned to the application. This simple code will be able to format as usual with `ToString("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt")` or any other format based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to understand a concept in time setting in clocks called [daylight saving time.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) In some countries around the world the clock is advanced by 1 or more hours to experience day light by one more hour. The difference between IST and GST is 5.30 hrs but the actual time difference is between New Delhi and London time is 6.30 hrs. See this article from [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215446/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081507-1.aspx) for setting and using server time.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Menu for mongo db date format]
To display DateTime on MongoDB is a good idea to use UTC display format (Zulu time).
This is a picture to show the menu example to enable this format using NoSQLBooster for MongoDB.

Answer (score -2):

On windows change your timezone.
Controll Panel -> Date and Time -> Change on timezone -> (UTC) Coordinated universal time.
And then just change your time