# spring data mongodb LocalDateTime conversion

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have got a simple Model & Repository classes as shown below:

**`StudentModel` class:**

```
@Document(collection = "student")
public final class StudentModel {

    @Id
    private final String name;

    private final LocalDateTime joiningDateTime;

    public StudentModel(String name, LocalDateTime joiningDateTime) {
        this.name = name;
        this.joiningDateTime = joiningDateTime;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getJoiningDateTime() {
        return joiningDateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StudentModel{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", joiningDateTime=" + joiningDateTime +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**`StudentRepository` class:**

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends MongoRepository<StudentModel, String> {
}
```

**`StudentTestingService` class:**

```
@Service
public class StudentTestingService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        studentRepository.save(new StudentModel("JOHN",
                LocalDateTime.of(2018, 4, 15, 9, 30, 0)));//line1
        System.out.println(" student saved to database !!!!!!! ");//line2
        StudentModel student = studentRepository.findOne("JOHN");//line3
        System.out.println("Joining DATE :"+student.getJoiningDateTime());//line4
    }
}
```

I run the above code inside a spring boot application (server runs at BST timezone).
As you could see above, my `StudentTestingService` class stores the `joiningDateTime` for the student (in BST) as "15-APR-2018 09:30:00"  (line1 above)
which is being saved inside the MongoDB database with the GMT time (i.e., "15-APR-2018 08:30:00") as shown in the below screen shot:
[image]
Now, when I query the record (at line3) and print it (line4), it prints in BST (though inside MongoDB database it is being stored as GMT time).

So, my question is, how and where does inside "spring-data-mongodb" code, these time conversions (locat time to GMT & GMT to localtime again) being handled/coded?

This seems quite basic and I am sure I am missing something here & lost.

Could you please point me to the "spring-data-mongodb" code base for this? If these conversions are not being handled inside "spring-data-mongodb", where does these being handled i.e., is it inside "mongo-java-driver" library classes ?

**Versions:**

Spring boot version: **1.5.10**

Mongo DB version: **3.4.9**

Comment: did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414158/mongodb-date-is-off-by-1-hour/32610959#32610959

Comment: Yes, it did not help anything w.r.to my spring-data question

Comment: Read here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/ & here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857763/spring-data-mongodb-when-saving-locadate-localdatetime-the-value-is-being-set